# How to move dart files in VSCode and keep imports correct

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

When I move my dart files inside VSCode, the imports throughout the project get messed up (they don't point to the new file's location automatically).

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCode does not allow extensions to participate (or catch) the renaming of a file. An [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43768) is in progress on this topic on the VSCode repo.

The Dart team is [waiting for it](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/548) to implement this feature.

edit: already implemented, just drag and drop the file, [release note](https://dartcode.org/releases/#v3110-2020-05-29)

Comment: Is this feature released yet?

Comment: Yes. It has been release in version 3.11 of the Dart Extension.

Comment: How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you use a Barrel. While moving the file, VSCode will change the export you have in your barrel-file. Main advantage is that the app is still running without errors. However, this export/import may need your attention (for proper structure purposes).

**Example:**

```
export 'edit_page.dart';
```

After moving the file to different folder, the barrel file was changed automatically:

```
export '../../edit_user/view/edit_page.dart';
```

And it didn't crash the application.